# While loop inside of for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to execute Python script which uses two nested loops.
The first one is for and second (the nested one is while).

Here is my code:

```
for currentData in data:
    currentState = ''
    count = 0
    while currentState == '': 
        currentState = someMetdhodExecution() ...
        count++
```

When I put `while` inside of `for` script crashes.

Could you please, help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, format your code. use four spaces to mark line as code.

Comment: `count++` is invalid syntax.

Comment: What is "crashes" supposed to mean?

Comment: Please fix your indention: four spaces for every level.

Comment: Please also be precise about the error. Python generates a detailed error traceback for you which you should show here.

Comment: count++ -> count += 1

Comment: Guys thank you very much! First I change count ++ to count = count +1
Second: I have missed one space for while and for this reason script crashes. I am not able to provide detail exception.
Thank you again I resolve the issue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having a `while` loop inside a `for` loop.

#### To demonstrate:

```
i = 0
kebab = ["chicken","garlic","cheese","tomato","lettuce","chilli"]    
print "Kebabs are so good, this is what mine has:"
excitement_over_kebab = 1    

for ingredients in kebab:    
    while excitement_over_kebab == 1:
        print kebab[i]
        i+=1
        if i == 6:
            print "Enough talk, my lunch break is over."
            excitement_over_kebab = 0
```

#### Output:

```
Kebabs are so good, this is what mine has:
chicken
garlic
cheese
tomato
lettuce
chilli
Enough talk, my lunch break is over.
```

Comment: You make me hungry. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't crash, it should give you a `SyntaxError` (at least, it isn't a execution error). The syntax `count++` doesn't exist in Python. You should use `count += 1`:

```
for currentData in data:
    currentState = ''
    count = 0
    while currentState == '': 
        currentState = someMethodExecution() ...
        count += 1
        #     ^^^^  note the modification here
```